# В чем разница между theme и style?

Tags: android

Наверно вы все замечали в XML что есть 2 параметра.

android:theme=""
и
android:style=""

По сути это одно и тоже. Можно указать ссылку на стиль и стиль будет применен. Так в чем же разница?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это разный scope. На примере единичной вьюхи вы может разницы и не увидите.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Для одного элемента это нормальное решение.

Но, скажем, если вы хотите применить стили на уровне всего приложения? Без тем не обойтись.

Вы определяете тему:

```
<style name="CustomFontStyle" parent="android:Theme.Light">
   ...
</style>
```

И потом назначаете её вашему приложению:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomFontStyle">
```

Ну, или `Activity`:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomFontStyle">
```

Всё, теперь тему будет применена на все элементы. Без тем вам бы пришлось в разметке назначать стили всем элементам. И в случае, если вы захотите сменить тему, менять.

Например, мы хотим все `TextView` сделать красными:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

И теперь надо только:

```
<application  android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Со стилями бы пришлось назначать каждой вьюхе:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Comment: Спс. граммотное объяснение